# how to create comboBox automaticly without submit, only fill some input

Tags: php

I'm sorry if my language's is so bad.
i have problems when i want to create comboBox automatically based on previous input.

```
<td>year<select name='year'>
            <option value=''/>
            <option value='2014'/>2014
            <option value='2015'/>2015
            </select>
        Offering
        <select name='offering'>
        <?php if(isset($_POST['year']){
         for($i=0;$i<10; $i++){
            echo '<option value='.$i.'>'.$i
          }
        }

            </select>
```

How I can use automatically when I fill the comboBox name 'year' without submit or without isset?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do either of two things:

1. Create

   ```
   <select name="offering" id="offering_2014" class="offering_select" disabled>
       <option value="x">x </option>
       ...
   </select> 
   <select name="offering" id="offering_2015" class="offering_select" disabled>
       <option value="y">y </option>
       ...
   </select>
   ```

And add jquery to show/hide & enable/disable the select box on the basis of change of `<select name='year'>` like this:

```
    $("select[name='year']").change(function(){
         $(".offering_select").hide(); // hide all offering select.
         $(".offering_select").prop("disabled", true); // disable all offering select.

         var year = $(this).val();
         var childId = "offering_" + year;
         var child = $("#" + childId);
         child.show(); // to remove display none.
         child.prop("disabled", false); // to enable select.
    });
```

2. You can fetch the select options using Ajax on the change event of select year.

   ```
   $("select[name='year']").change(function(){
      $.ajax({
         //Write ajax call here
          success: function(){
             //Create HTML and use .html()/.append() to add it to DOM.    
          },
      });
   });
   ```

Hope This helps.

Cheers!